# Can't access NAS from desktop Linux Mint using Nemo, yet no problem accessing it from Win11 or Linux Mint laptop, also using Nemo

Tags: linux-mint, nas

I can access my openmediavault5 NAS no problem from my Linux Mint desktop, using Nemo. I decided to go with a QNAP NAS, since it has 2.5Gb ethernet. Hoping to see faster file transfer speeds. I can access the QNAP from my Win11 box and my Linux Mint laptop using Nemo, but not from my desktop Linux using Nemo. In my desktop, under Nemo, QNAP shows up as  (File Sharing). There are two of these identical entries. Clicking on either i get "Unable to mount location - Failed to retrieve share list from server: Invalid argument". How can this be when i can easily access the NAS from other devices?

Comment: To the guy here who recommended i use NFS to access my server from my Ubuntu desktop - i got it working and i'm a very happy guy. Thanks for your suggestion.